# Google Kubernetes is not auto scaling to 0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am testing the Google Kubernetes autoscaling.

I have created a cluster with 1 master node.

Then I have used

```
gcloud container node-pools create node-pool-test \
--machine-type g1-small --cluster test-master \
--num-nodes 1 --min-nodes 0 --max-nodes 3 \
--enable-autoscaling --zone us-central1-a
```

to create a node pool with autoscaling and minimum node to 0.

Now, the problem is that it's been 30 minutes since the node pool was created (and I haven't run any pods) but the node pool is not scaling down to 0. It was supposed to scale down in 10 minutes.

[Some system pods are running on this node pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJyZq.png) but the master node is also running them.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#minimum_and_maximum_node_pool_size):

> If you specify a minimum of zero nodes, an idle node pool can scale
>   down completely. However, at least one node must always be available
>   in the cluster to run system Pods.

and also check the limitations [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#limitations) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node):

> Occasionally, cluster autoscaler cannot scale down completely and an
>   extra node exists after scaling down. This can occur when required
>   system Pods are scheduled onto different nodes, because there is no
>   trigger for any of those Pods to be moved to a different node

and possible [workaround](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/).

More information you can find at [Autoscaler FAQ](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-can-i-scale-a-node-group-to-0).

Also, as a solution, you could create one [node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools) with a small machine for system pods, and an additional node pool with a big machine where you would run your workload. This way the second node pool can scale down to 0 and you still have space to run the system pods. [Here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/scale-your-kubernetes-cluster-to-almost-zero-with-gke-autoscaler-9c78051cbf40) you can find an example.